# Trying to use multiprocessing to fill an array in python

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have a code like this

```
x = 3;
y = 3;
z = 10;
ar = np.zeros((x,y,z))

from multiprocessing import Process, Pool

para = []
process = []
def local_func(section):
    print "section %s" % str(section)
    ar[2,2,section] = 255
    print "value set %d", ar[2,2,section]

pool = Pool(1)

run_list = range(0,10)
list_of_results = pool.map(local_func, run_list)

print ar
```

The value in ar was not changed with multithreading, what might be wrong?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using multiple processes here, not multiple threads. Because of that, each instance of `local_func` gets its own separate copy of `ar`. You can use a [custom `Manager`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/multiprocessing.html#customized-managers) to create a shared numpy array, which you can pass to each child process and get the results you expect:

```
import numpy as np
from functools import partial
from multiprocessing import Process, Pool
import multiprocessing.managers

x = 3;
y = 3;
z = 10; 

class MyManager(multiprocessing.managers.BaseManager):
    pass
MyManager.register('np_zeros', np.zeros, multiprocessing.managers.ArrayProxy)


para = []
process = []
def local_func(ar, section):
    print "section %s" % str(section)
    ar[2,2,section] = 255 
    print "value set %d", ar[2,2,section]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    m = MyManager()
    m.start()
    ar = m.np_zeros((x,y,z))

    pool = Pool(1)

    run_list = range(0,10)
    func = partial(local_func, ar)
    list_of_results = pool.map(func, run_list)

    print ar
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, multi-threading and multi-processing are different things.

With multi-threading threads share access to the same array.

With multi-processing each process has its own copy of the array.

Answer (score 1):

[`multiprocessing.Pool`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) is a **process** pool, not a thread pool.

If you want thread pool, use `multiprocess.pool.ThreadPool`:

---

Replace:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
```

with:

```
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool as Pool
```

Comment: @tanyonder Keep in mind that when you use threads instead of processes, you don't get true concurrent execution of your threads, because of the GIL.

Comment: Then it only spawns one thread on a multicore desktop, is there something else wrong?

Comment: @dano, I think you meant parallelism.

Comment: @tanyonder You're telling it to only create one thread, by passing `1` to the `Pool` constructor. Just call `Pool()` and it will create a `Pool` with `multiprocessing.cpu_count()` threads.

Comment: @dano, The Pool(1) was a test, I meant to run it with more than one thread, but it did not work, so I tried to see if Pool(1) would change any. thanks